# Vim: x-terminal key mapping

Tags: vim

I normally use Vim on Windows and have had no problems with key-mapping, but now that I'm using a virtual machine running Ubuntu, accessed through MobaXterm, things don't quite work as they should. That includes basic things like `<c-s>` for save and `<F5>` for run, which I can't live without. I've done my research and read materials that seem to address this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519532/mapping-function-keys-in-vim) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim)), but they went well over my head. Frankly, having to press `<c-v>` before a function key is downright weird. And it didn't even work when I tried. Can somebody explain, please? As a test case, if I want to map `<F2>` to `:pwd`, what do I have to do?

To my delight, I've found that my key-mappings *do* work as intended on Ubuntu's gVim, so I'll be using that. I still would like the answer, though, because I actually prefer the quick and easy feel of plain old vim on the terminal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MobaXterm. It looks like a packaged version of some open-source things like X and xterm; but I wonder if you might have more luck just running X in the VM and running xterm (or one of the million other terminals) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to live without <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> because that is the terminal command to stop output (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> undoes that).

Other function keys should be mappable without any problem, just enter `:map` , then hit the function key you want to map which should show e.g.`<F5>` for F5, then space, then what you want the key to map to.

You can put that line (without the leading colon) in your `~/.vimrc` file to enable the mapping for every vim session.

If you've tried that then please edit your question to show what exactly you tried and what the result was (and how that differed from your expectations).

EDIT:
If you want to map sequences that aren't defined in the terminal definition, then you can manually map the sequence.

First you need to find out what bytes/characters it sent when you press e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. I always use `od -c` for this; start the command, press the key sequence, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to send an end-of-file to the command, which then prints the decoded version:

```
$ od -c
^[[24^
0000000 033   [   2   4   ^  \n
0000006
```

So this is escape, [, 2, 4, ^ (the newline is what I entered after the sequence and should be ignored; you can also hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> twice but then the output is started after the input and looks messed up).

Now we know the sequence, and can add the mapping to `.vimrc`. Add a line such as the following:

```
map <C-[>[24^ :whateveryouwant
```

The `<C-[>` sequence is the vim representation of escape, which is the same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. After that the characters aren't special so they can be entered as-is.

Now <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> will be mapped to the right hand side you entered when you start vim.

Comment: Actually, you can make the terminal ignore ^S/^Q for flow control by running `stty -ixon` (and preferably putting it in your shell startup file).

Comment: Thanks for addressing the `<c-s>` limitation, but your suggestion is what I have already. Of course, I put my usual mappings in my .vimrc, the problem is that some of them don't work on terminal Vim. They do work in gVim (Ubuntu), though. The second link in the original post says "In the GUI version of Vim (gvim), the mapping of keys seem to work for the most part... for terminal versions of Vim, mapping something like Ctrl-Shift-F2 needs some extra work.", so it's a known issue. I'm just curious why.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed addition. Should I take it, then, that the function keys aren't in my terminal definition, and that's why my straightforward mapping for `<F5>` (no shift, no ctrl) wasn't working?

Comment: You can use the `infocmp` command to generate a readable version of your terminal's definition. The `kfXX` entries are the keyboard function definitions, <F5> is `kf5`. `\E` is the representation of the `escape` character. Compare that to what `od -c` displays.